# Getting a Mathematica Menu Bar on Linux

Tags: menu, wolfram-mathematica, palette

The Linux front end of Mathematica (8.0.1.0) does not seem to have a Menu Bar which is apart from any given notebook. In any Windows front end I have used, there is a standalone Menu Bar which contains the usual: "File, Edit, Insert, Format, Cell, Graphics, Evaluation, Palettes, Window, Help". Each of the notebooks on my Linux front end have this menu, but I am looking to have one which stands alone.

In particular, I am looking to use the "Generate Notebook From Palette" option located in the Palette portion of the Menu Bar. The reason I require the stand alone bar is that the palette I want to convert to a notebook, the DocumentationTools palette which comes with Wolfram Workbench 2, does not have its own Menu Bar. Attempting to use the menu bar from a notebook associates the possible options with that notebook whereas, if I had a stand alone Menu Bar, I could make it so the 'active' notebook is this palette and then go to town converting the palette to a notebook.

In short:

How can I obtain a stand alone Menu Bar on a Linux front end of Mathematica?

or

How can I convert a palette to a notebook without a Menu Bar?

or

Does the DocumentationTools palette which comes with Wolfram Workbench 2 exist in a directory as a notebook file that I may be able to snag?

Comment: Have you tried "Generate notebook from palette" under the "Palette" menu? One could try to do it programmatically but if doing that works...

Comment: The trouble with this is that that option is associated to the 'active' notebook. The only place I have that menu option is in another Mathematica notebook, apart from the palette. If I go into that other notebook's "Palette" menu, that notebook will be the 'active' one. I need the palette itself to be the 'active' window in order to utilize the "Palette" menu. I think I may have found the DocumentationTools palette itself in the file browser. I will post back with more information soon.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work under OS X so I can't guarantee that it will work on Linux, but to create a palette programmatically you could try the following

- Open the Palette you're interested in,
- Execute `Notebooks[]`
- Set `nb` to whatever the notebook is belonging to the Palette
- Run `FrontEndTokenExecute[nb, "GenerateNotebook"]`

It should then open a Notebook version in a new window.